# Websphere 9 - SpringBoot - "Start is not a valid operation"

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere, websphere-9

I have a hello-world spring app with only the @SpringBootApplication class that I'm trying to deploy to websphere 9. It's built using gradle that is bundled using the ear plugin and The only thing in my build.gradle is the buidscript {} which defines the maven repo, the classpath to the gradle plugin, spring version and oracle version. and

```
 ear {
    appDirectory = file('src/main/java')
  }
```

then the list of depedencies. and I have an empty application.properties file. but when I try to start it on websphere I get "Start is not a valid operation"

I also noticed when installing it didnt let me select the module like it normally does which leads me to think that something is wrong. and the google searches for "Start is not a valid operation" are non-existent which i think is odd since my app is so basic so Im surpised no one else has run into this? Im sorry for not providing more code but my project is on my work machine which doesnt let me access stackoverflow.... if you need more info I will try to provide. I'm completely stumped. thanks.

UPDATE:
I also notice that in installApps -> cell -> the spring app ear name is not found. Why could that be? And when I restart was9 after the spring app is installed. It doesnt even attempt to start the spring app

But the deployment.xml can be found in config->cells-> cell -> applications -> myapp.ear

why could this be??

Comment: When deploying and starting the app, are there any messages in server logs or FFDC?

Comment: @FRowe no, it doesnt even attempt to start the app. when i manually try to start from the admin console. i get the message I outlayed above

Comment: and adding to my above comment, nothing shows up in the logs either when I try to manually start it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by creating a new directory and moving everything into that directory. Then in the parent directory I created new build.gradle and settings.gradle. and I built the sub directory as a war and the parent project as an ear.